# keyboard setInputAccessoryView buttons not firing

Tags: iphone, events, button, keyboard

I want to show next previous buttons above the keyboard. I call  function "makeToolBars" from viewDidLoad to create it. The application does display the buttons correctly but when I click on them I get error it does not go to "goToNextField" function.

Can anyone point how to correct it ?

```
-(void)goToNextField:(id)sender
{
    [txtPassword resignFirstResponder];
    [txtUserName becomeFirstResponder];
}

-(void) makeToolBars
{
    UIToolbar *toolbar1 = [[[UIToolbar alloc] init] autorelease];
    [toolbar1 setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
    [toolbar1 sizeToFit];

    UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Next"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(goToNextField)];

    UIBarButtonItem *flexButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

    NSArray *itemsArray1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: nextButton,flexButton1, nil];

    [flexButton1 release];
    [nextButton release];
    [toolbar1 setItems:itemsArray1];

    [txtUserName setInputAccessoryView:toolbar1];


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below statement is wrong.

```
UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Next"
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(goToNextField)];
```

use the below modified correct code .

```
UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Next"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(goToNextField:)];
```

Because you might forget to append colon in `goToNextField` (Correct `goToNextField:`).

And in your function implementation for `goToNextField` you were considering the colon and put `:(id) sender` in your function.

Answer (score 1):

You've written `action:@selector(goToNextField)];`. It should be `action:@selector(goToNextField:)];`